# Forward and Reverse geocoding in single app : Need Direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geocoding, core-location

I did reverse geocoding on a button click which was working fine using CLLocationManagerDelegate. But now I took a UISearchBar to take place name from user and on button click I want to show the place entered by user and a marker on it.
As geocoding takes some time no value is stored in location but the app finishes its work. 
So can anyone tell me how to do it ? and please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

```
   - (IBAction)searchLocation:(id)sender {

        NSString *address = self.searchBar.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",address);

        [forwardGeocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if ([placemarks count]>0) {

                CLPlacemark *placeMarkForward = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                locationValue = placeMarkForward.location;
                NSLog(@"Location : :%@",locationValue);

            }
        }];

        [reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationValue completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (error == nil && [placemarks count]>0) {
                CLPlacemark *placeMarkReverse = [placemarks lastObject];
                CLLocation *currentLocation;
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
                marker.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placeMarkReverse.country];

                marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", placeMarkReverse.locality,placeMarkReverse.postalCode];
                marker.map = mapView_;
            }
        }];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way and its working now. Correct me if I am doing it in a messy way.
Here is the answer if anyone wants to do it :

```
#pragma mark - Serach Location -
- (IBAction)searchLocation:(id)sender {

    NSString *address = self.searchBar.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",address);



    [forwardGeocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if ([placemarks count]>0) {

            CLPlacemark *placeMarkForward = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            locationValue = placeMarkForward.location;
            NSLog(@"Location : :%@",locationValue);

            [reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationValue completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                if (error == nil && [placemarks count]>0) {
                    CLPlacemark *placeMarkReverse = [placemarks lastObject];

                    NSLog(@"Testing");
                    [mapView_ animateToLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationValue.coordinate.latitude,locationValue.coordinate.longitude)];
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationValue.coordinate.latitude,locationValue.coordinate.longitude);
                    marker.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placeMarkReverse.locality];

                    marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", placeMarkReverse.postalCode,placeMarkReverse.country];
                    marker.map = mapView_;
                }
            }];

        }

    }];


}
```